# Extract the_excerpt from the_content

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to create a filter to display only the text of a the_content without the images. But not working, I tried it but it does not display anything, it is blank

```
add_filter('the_content', 'importgaleria');

function importgaleria($content) {
    global $post;
    if (is_singular()) {
        $content=$post->post_excerpt;
        return $content;
    } else {
        return $content;
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you want to display only text not image right ?

Comment: Yes, I want only the text is displayed

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve with this code

```
add_filter('the_content', 'importgaleria');

function importgaleria($content) {
       if (is_singular()) {
        $content =  wp_trim_words(get_the_content(), 20, '' ) ;
        return $content;

    } else {
        return $content;
     };

};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try below code

```
add_filter('the_content', 'importgaleria');

function importgaleria($content) {
    global $post;
    if (is_singular()) {
        $content=$post->post_excerpt;
        $content = preg_replace('/(<)([img])(\w+)([^>]*>)/', '', $content);
        $content = str_replace(']]>', ']]&gt;', $content);
        return $content;
    } else {
        return $content;
     };

};
```

Comment: This also did not work, he disappears with the text and images of the post

Comment: Are you really on a singular page? (and btw, first hit on google: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/162165/62744)